# turn off clang optimization, remove phi instruction

Tags: optimization, llvm, clang

1) Is it possible to turn off any optimization in clang?

2) Is there a way to remove any phi instruction from generated llvm code?

I use clang with options:
clang test.c -Wimplicit -emit-llvm  -g -O0  -c -o result.bc

And for some source files clang emit llvm code with phi-instructions.
I find any wat to get llvm-file without phi-instructions.

Comment: I am far from being an LLVM expert, but I would have thought the phi-instructions necessary to the IR... Are they not ?

Comment: Maybe phi-instructions are useful for IR code. But they are not necessary. For example llvm-gcc generates llvm code for the same file without phi-instructions. And also clang is able to generate llvm code without any phi for many source files.

Comment: what's the problem with phoney nodes? Are you implementing your own backend? In this case, you'd be better off with using a decent SSA for your register scheduling, even if your target is, say, a stack machine. Otherwise - just use `reg2mem` pass to get everything moved onto stack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use LLVM's reg2mem pass to get rid of any phi's. Just feed you .bc out of clang into opt -reg2mem and you're done

Comment: How does that get rid of phi nodes?

Comment: Changes them to loads and stores to stack-allocated variables.

Comment: Oh, and then you just jump to a single location. That's a good idea... :-)

Comment: Long were gone the days when "reg2mem" passed killed *all* the phi instructions, if that ever happened at all. The modern description of reg2mem reads: "This file demotes all registers to memory references. It is intended to be the inverse of mem2reg. By converting to load instructions, the only values live across basic blocks are alloca instructions and load instructions before phi nodes." And clang indeed dares to generate phi instructions (e.g. for `?:` ternary operator) nowadays with loads in pred bblocks, which reg2mem then can't kill (even though it's trivial). Touche.

Comment: Ok, traced that to https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/ce1de6172cbf7c7bf5cbbb4bbaba4940023a5c2e, dated 2011-01-26. So, to the time @AntonKorobeynikov posted this answer, it already wasn't true (though perhaps untrue clang wasn't yet released).